# Changing math font in Classicthesis

Tags: fonts, math-mode, classicthesis

I'm using the popular Classicthesis template for my thesis. I like almost everything of this template apart from the math font (it should be the one loaded with Mathpazo) and since I have to write lots of formulae, I'd like to restore the classic modern font.

So my question is the following: how can I change ONLY the math font, preserving the palatino font for text in Classicthesis? I read that palatino and modern math font don't go together because of "aesthetic" reasons, but I don't care about that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't use the option `eulermath` for `classicthesis`? The Euler font for math is really nice.

MWE

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[eulermath]{classicthesis}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

Some math $x+y+z=15$.
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Anyway, if you really want Computer Modern as the math font, add the following lines in your preamble

```
\SetSymbolFont{operators}   {normal}{OT1}{cmr} {m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}     {normal}{OML}{cmm} {m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}     {normal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{normal}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}   {bold}  {OT1}{cmr} {bx}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}     {bold}  {OML}{cmm} {b}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}     {bold}  {OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{bold}  {OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}

\SetMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{normal}{OT1}{cmr}{bx}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{normal}{OT1}{cmss}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{normal}{OT1}{cmr}{m}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathtt}{normal}{OT1}{cmtt}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{bold}  {OT1}{cmr}{bx}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{bold}  {OT1}{cmss}{bx}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{bold}  {OT1}{cmr}{bx}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathtt}{bold}  {OT1}{cmtt}{m}{n}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{classicthesis}

\SetSymbolFont{operators}   {normal}{OT1}{cmr} {m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}     {normal}{OML}{cmm} {m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}     {normal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{normal}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}   {bold}  {OT1}{cmr} {bx}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}     {bold}  {OML}{cmm} {b}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}     {bold}  {OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{bold}  {OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}

\SetMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{normal}{OT1}{cmr}{bx}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{normal}{OT1}{cmss}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{normal}{OT1}{cmr}{m}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathtt}{normal}{OT1}{cmtt}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{bold}  {OT1}{cmr}{bx}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{bold}  {OT1}{cmss}{bx}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{bold}  {OT1}{cmr}{bx}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathtt}{bold}  {OT1}{cmtt}{m}{n}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

Some math $x+y+z=15$.
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]